# PHP/SQL Login Form - how to check password in database

Tags: php, html, sql

at the moment, i check the username and passwort of a HTML form like this on my database:

```
$exc = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, cid, fullname FROM user WHERE username LIKE :username AND password LIKE :password");
```

I need to check both **CASE SENSITIVE** when executing the query.

Database data:

```
username: louis
password: goal43
```

Form data:

```
username: LOUIS
password: GOAL43
```

returns **true** - how do i fix this ?

Comment: You've prepared the query! That's an important step done! The next step is to execute it!

Comment: `LIKE` is case-insensitive use `=` instead.

Comment: Tried to check this link. It might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142512/pdo-bindparam-case-sensitive

Comment: You mean the BINARY in front of password ? gonna check that now.

Comment: LIKE is also a whole lot of fun if I have a `%` in the username (or password if they're being stored as plaintext) that I enter in the login form.... e.g. `a%` will probably return quite a lot of records

Comment: @SherwinObciana thats the solution i was looking for - BINARY in front of the password / username.

Comment: Just curious, why are you storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: my project is under delevoping at the moment, there has been no time for security yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$exc = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, cid, fullname FROM user WHERE BINARY username LIKE :username AND BINARY password LIKE :password");
```

I hope it helps you. The link I've given to you

Answer (score 0):

You have written query in prepare. Next step to assign parameters to `:username` and `:password` parameter you can do the by `bindParam()`. Which is given below.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, cid, fullname FROM user WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$stmt->bindParam(':username ', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Why negative vote? Please provide proper explanation

Comment: @ downvoter, whats the wrong in Pankaj Makwana solution  ?

Comment: The OP is most likely executing the query, the OP asked `I want to check if the letters are upper or lowercase`

Comment: i need to check for upper and lowercase - sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

just use `=` instead of `LIKE`

`LIKE` is case-insensitive

Comment: Yes, i didn't know about the BINARY also.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already asked and contains answer , you can see this link there are very good answers for your query
[Compare string with case sensitive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969059/sql-case-sensitive-string-compare)

Comment: these are just other solutions.

Comment: yes but you can use them to solve yours query , you can use like as well as = , but if you use = then query must be like this 
Select * from a_table where attribute = 'k' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 
this will match if cases of characters are matched